# Live Agent: Pass parameters entered in Pre chat form to a VF Page on Accepting the chat Request

Tags: visualforce, community, liveagent, parameters

I have a pre chat form and the app is configured to open a VF page when the chat request is accepted. I want to pass parameters entered in the pre chat form to this VF page. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `getDetailsByPrimaryTabId()` method available in *Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit*. This will return the details of the chat associated with a specific primary tab ID. See this [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getDetailsByPrimaryTabId.htm) for more details.

Example VF page provided in the above mentioned link.

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/29.0/integration.js"/>
    <a href="#" onClick="testGetDetailsByPrimaryTabId();">Get Chat Details</a> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function testGetDetailsByPrimaryTabId() {
            //Get the value for 'myPrimaryTabId'from the getPrimaryTabIds() or getEnclosingPrimaryTabId() methods. 
            //These values are for example purposes only
            var primaryTabId = 'myPrimaryTabId';
            sforce.console.chat.getDetailsByPrimaryTabId(primaryTabId, getDetailsSuccess);
        }

        function getDetailsSuccess(result) {
            //Report whether accepting the chat was succesful
            if (result.success == true) {
                console.log(result);
                chatKey = result.details.chatKey;
                alert('The chatKey for this chat is: ' + chatKey);
            } else {
                alert('Getting the details was not Succesful');
            }
        };

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

You can get all the pre-chat form details from the result JS object as below.

```
result.details.customDetails[0].value
result.details.customDetails[1].value
result.details.customDetails[2].value
...........
...........
```